# How do I open sub window after I click on button on main screen in PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

HI I am trying to make a simple converter.
I have used PyQt4 designed to make the Gui
I want to know how launch a new window after I click on the individual button.

This is the interface I have created using PyQt4 Designer.
Here is the Image link :

[image: a]

and I want to launch this windows when I click on currency button.
Here is the Image Link:

[image: b]

Here is my code for **main.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from main_screen import mainscreen

def main():
    import sys
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = mainscreen()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and code for **mainscreen.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from window_main import Ui_MainWindow

class mainscreen(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
                super(mainscreen,self).__init__(parent)
                self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
                self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

How can I open new window after I click on currency button (object name for currency button is "currency_bt")
and do I have to write the code for currency in same window or I have to write in new window.
How do I do it.

I am new to Python Gui programming.

Answer (score 7):

Each GUI form that you create in Qt Designer needs to be converted into a python module using pyuic. So, to start with, you need to do the same for `currency.ui` that you did for `window_main`.

Now you can import your currency window class into `mainscreen.py`, and connect a button to handler so you can display it.

The code would look something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from window_main import Ui_MainWindow
from currency import Ui_CurrencyWindow

class CurrencyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_CurrencyWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CurrencyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

class MainScreen(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.currencyButton.clicked.connect(self.handleCurrencyButton)

    def handleCurrencyButton(self):
        window = CurrencyWindow(self)
        window.show()
```

After looking at this example code, it will probably occur to you that you are going to end up importing *a lot* of modules, and have *a lot* of boiler-plate code to write for each one of them (which is not much fun).

So I would advise you to consider changing your GUI design, so that you have one main window containing a tabwidget, and then have a separate tab for each of your converters. This will not only make your application *much* easier to write, but it should also make it a lot nicer to use.

Comment: Thank You! you have been really helpful brother.

Comment: @kartikjagdale if you find any answer useful, please vote up. If an answer answered your question and cleared your doubt please go ahead and accept it.

Comment: hey @kartikg3, I tried to upvote the answer, but I don't have a reputation, it requires to have 50 reputation to upvote a answer. but yeah I will make sure to upvote the answer, when I reach that level.

Answer (score 3):

I'm making my bachelor thesis in PyQt4. First I also wanted to use the designer (generating code is nice), but afterall I was not using it during my work. Maybe it's a matter of taste.
But for your question (I did this without the QtDesigner):

Let's say we have a main window class:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class mainscreen(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(mainscreen,self).__init__(parent)

            self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("push")
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.pushed)

        @pyqtSlot()
        def pushed(self):
            # in this section here you can create the new window and show it


 qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = mainscreen()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

There are some good tutorials (http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/ helped me getting started).

Comment: Thank you! you have been really helpful, but I will prefer Pyqt4 designer over writing all Gui codes.

Comment: If you want to get serious with PyQt, it is strongly recommended not to use qtdesigner.

Comment: hey @kartikg3 , thank you for your suggestion, but I guess qtdesigner is like a motivation for beginners to get their hands dirty on gui, otherwise you'll easily get discouraged by command line coding the gui.

Comment: Yeah if you are beginning its good to start with, but as I said once you start getting serious with Qt, hand coding the elements is cleaner. Check out this article: http://www.robg3d.com/2014/08/geocities-and-the-qt-designer/

Comment: For anyone coming across this this in the future, I just want to say I completely disagree with the suggestion that you should code the GUI in preference to using QT designer. Any UI bigger than 5 widgets will be faster to create in Qt Designer. If this was not true, then the creators of Qt would never have made Qt Designer.

Answer (score -2):

Make two programs: **main_win.py**   and  **second_win.py**, then in *main_win.py* put this lines:

```
from os import system as sh               //In the begin

def openewin(self):                       //In the class main_win
    sh("python second_win.py")
```

Ready, just connect the push button to function openewin!