# Cannot open multiple frame in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to open a new window once a button is clicked using Python PyQt library. Currently, I can create two buttons in my frame but I cannot click the first button where it should open a new window and hide my first window. There I have created a back button for it to go back to my first window. Can anyone help to teach me how to create a new window and using button click to open a new window.

This is my Python code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()


    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
    self.setWindowTitle("Testing Window")
    # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(''))
    self.home()

def home(self):

    btn = QtGui.QPushButton("QR Code", self)
    btn.clicked.connect(self.qr)

    btn.resize(100, 100)
    btn.move(100, 100)

    btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Face Recognition", self)
    btn1.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

    btn1.resize(200, 100)
    btn1.move(300, 100)


    self.show()

def qr(self):
    backbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Back" , self)
    backbtn.clicked.connect(self.home)

    backbtn.resize(100, 100)
    backbtn.move(100, 100)

    self.show()

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    # GUI1 = QRCode()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only one window in your code, the one you instantiate with `GUI=Window()`.

Your function `qr` does not create a new window, it:

- creates a third button on the same window
- try to show the window, which has no effect since the window is already shown. The third button doesn't appear because it's created after the first call to `self.show()`

To open a new window on a button click, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572985/4720935). You can use `hide()` for the first window.

On a side note, for a basic GUI you don't need `QMainWindow`, a simple `QWidget` will work fine. Also, you might want to look at layouts instead of absolute positioning.

Comment: Are there any ways to instantiate my second window ?

Comment: See the link to a similar question/answer I provided