# Python QT. Form from another Form

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

First i am beginning in programming :)

I create in QT Designer Form ( MainForm) and add function  in button to open a new form. I do this step from 
[How do I open sub window after I click on button on main screen in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567208/how-do-i-open-sub-window-after-i-click-on-button-on-main-screen-in-pyqt4) ( First anwser) but when i compile I got:

> 'Ui_V1' object has no attribute 'show'

Where is the problem.
thanks :)

this is a part of code in main form.py:

```
from V1 import Ui_V1
#V1 class and form
self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.openV1())
def openV1(self):
    window=Ui_V1()
    window.show()
```

OK i solved this by watching video on Yt :D

```
def openV1(self):
    self.V1Window=QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.ui= Ui_V1()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.V1Window)
    self.V1Window.show()
```

and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your code to python? By default it will be a ui file. You can use `pyuic4.exe` file.

```
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\something> pyuic4.exe full/path/to/input.ui -o full/path/to/output.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the generated file. Usually `pyuic4` generates a class that is not a QtWidget it is just a factory with a `setupUI` method.

I usually do this:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_V1):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then you can use your `MyForm` as a regular widget.

Comment: Generates this:
 class Ui_V1(object):
    def setupUi(self, V1):
        V1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("V1"))
        V1.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(V1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 46, 25))

Comment: The method `setupUi` is what you have to call with `self` as an argument